# need some C wget

Tags: c, linux, wget

This is my very first C program there are some spots that I am not sure about and dying for help. This is the program to download files from links in a text file. Thank you!!!!!!

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
using std::printf;

FILE *file; /*declare the file pointer*/
char line [LINE_MAX];

//Parent process

int main()
{
pid_t  pid;

file= fopen ("links.txt", "rt"); /*open file and read it*/
numberOfChildren = 0;
string url;
while (fgets (line,LINE_MAX, file) !=NULL) /*NOT SURE*/
++numberOfChildren;
/* fork another process */
pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) { /* error occurred */
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
        execlp("/usr/bin/wget", "wget", <url>, NULL);/*NOT SURE*/
    }
    while (numberOfChildren>0) { /* parent process */
    /* parent will wait for the child to complete */
        wait (NULL);
        --numberOfChildren;
        printf ("Child Complete");

        exit(0);
    }


}
```

Comment: Well, if this really is your first C program, then you skipped the easy stuff and went straight to intermediate I would say. Also, have you tried this? Does it work? If not, what happens? What's the output if any?

Comment: What do you need help with? `/* Not sure */` does not explain your problem well enough. Maybe add some verbs and adjectives to that comment with what you are not sure about.

Comment: While you main loop might be C. Several headers are C++ and you have C++ keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the subject of the question ("need some C wget") and your comment `/* Not Sure */`, I guess that you are searching for a library that gives you a wget-like functionality. Have you checked out *libcurl* yet? It offers a very easy API for simple file transfers. Take a look into [this simple example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html), which should tell you about the basics. To see how to actually write a file (and not only request it), take a look into their [FTP example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpget.html) (specifically, into the option `CURL_WRITEFUNCTION`).